# Windows Hello Biometrics with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, biometrics, windows-hello

Is it possible to use windows hello with python? For example, if anyone has ever used dashlane (password manager), you can use windows hello to unlock your account or retrieve passwords. Is it possible to use windows hello (pin, IR face scanner, etc) with python?

I tried using [this](https://github.com/luspock/FingerPrint) GitHub repo (nothing happens after running the code) and searching on DuckDuckGo, but no results.

Original post (reddit, no replies): https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/dd35rq/windows_hello_biometrics_with_python/